# how analytically (or with matlab) can i find the solution to the following algebraic problem?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, matlab

Here is the problem: find $x_k$'s ($x_k\in R$) such that

$\max_{i} \{|c_i+\sum_k x_k d_{ki}| \}=\gamma$,

where $c_i$ and $d_{ki}$ are constant numbers in $R$.

I'm looking for the set of $x_k$ that satisfies the above condition.

For example

$\max\{|2-3x_1+x_2|,|1+2x_1+x_2|\}=1$,

---

Edited: to make the example more clear.

Consider this one

$\max\{|2-3x_1+x_2|,|1+2x_1+x_2|, |1-x_1-x_2|\}=1$,

That is, the number of equations is not equal to the number of variables.

Answer (score 2):

If we are given $m$ linear functions
$$\phi_i:\quad{\mathbb R}^n\to{\mathbb R}, \qquad x\mapsto \phi_i(x):=\langle d_i,x\rangle +c_i\qquad(1\leq i\leq m)$$
and a real $\gamma>0$ the $2m$ inequalities
$$-\gamma\leq \phi_i(x)\leq \gamma\qquad(1\leq i\leq m)$$
define a convex polytope $P\subset{\mathbb R}^n$ (which may be empty, and need not be bounded). The set you are interested in is the boundary $\partial P$ of this polytope. This boundary can have a complicated combinatorial structure. The possible numbers of vertices, edges, $\ldots$, facets form an intensive area of research. This is to say that your problem is computationally hard as soon as $m$ and $n$ get larger.

A simple case is treated in the following first version of this answer:

Assume that the matrix $D=[d_{ki}]$  is square and nonsingular, and consider the affine map
$$A:\quad x\mapsto y:=D'x+c\ .$$
(Your indexing of the $d_{ki}$ is somewhat unfortunate, therefore the $'\>$) You are interested in the set $$S:=\{x\in{\mathbb R}^n\>|\>\max_i|y_i|=\gamma\}\ .$$
Now the set $\{y\in {\mathbb R}^n\>|\>\max_i|y_i|=\gamma\}$ is the surface $\partial C$ of the $n$-dimensional cube $$C:=\{y\in {\mathbb R}^n\>|\>-\gamma\leq y_i\leq\gamma \  (1\leq i\leq n)\}\ ,$$
and is the union of $2n$ such cubes of one dimension less (an ordinary $3$-dimensional cube has $6$ two-dimensional square faces).

It follows that
$$S=A^{-1}(\partial C)=(D')^{-1}(\partial C -c)\ .$$

Comment: Thanks! but note that the dimension of y is not necessarily the same as x So that means D is not square and thus cannot be inverted to find the x uniquely.  I did'nt get your point when you say "...and is the union of 2n2n such cubes of one dimension less."

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** The answer below gives **one** and **all** solutions for the problem of finding a $x_k\in\mathbb{R}$ such that

$\max_i\{\lvert c_i+\sum_k x_k d_{ki}\rvert\}=\gamma$

where $c_i$ and $d_{ki}$ are constant numbers in $\mathbb{R}$.

The solution for the problem of finding **all** the possibles $x_k$ that satisfies the equation above is given after the approach that finds one solution.

## For one solution:

I've found the following solution method, verify if it fits your requirements.
I focused on the solution of the example but it might work for any problem.

Note that any solution for you problem lies on the border of the following region

\begin{gather}
-1 \leq 2 - 3x_1 + x_2 \leq 1\\
-1 \leq 1 +2x_1 +2x_2 \leq 1
\end{gather}

Therefore solving the optimization problem 
\begin{align}
\max\quad &c^Tx\\
\textrm{s.t.:}\quad&-1 \leq 2 - 3x_1 + x_2 \leq 1\\
&-1 \leq 1 +2x_1 +2x_2 \leq 1
\end{align}
where $c$ is a nonzero vector, will result in a solution that satisfies your conditions.

The feasible region is shown in the following plot

[image: Feasible region]

## For all solutions:

For all solutions you can do a similar approach, create a polyhedron given by the convex relaxation of the problem. The equations are given by 
\begin{align}
-\gamma \leq c_i+\sum_k x_k d_{ki}\leq \gamma
\end{align}
for all $i$.

Then use a vertex enumeration algorithm to obtain all the vertex of the polyhedron. Suggested links

- [2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/138494/finding-the-vertices-of-a-convex-polyhedron-from-a-set-of-planes) - related question in the mathoverflow,
- [3](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02293050) - Avis-Fukuda Algorithm for Vertex Enumeration Problems (A pivoting algorithm for convex hulls and vertex enumeration of arrangements and polyhedra),
- [4](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF02162916) - Old paper about the subject might be interesting option.

You can find more over internet over the keyword "Vertex enumeration problem".

Comment: thanks! but what is C vector exactly?

Comment: The vector $c$ is any non-zero vector. 
We choose a objective function because we want a solution that is in the border of the feasible region.

Comment: with this approach can we get the white region? or let's say at least the corners of the region?

Comment: The white region is the region such that $\lvert2−3x_1+x_2 \rvert \leq 1$ and $\lvert 1+2x1+x2 \rvert\leq 1$. The solution of optimization LP  is always in the border of the feasible region, therefore $\lvert2−3x_1+x_2 \rvert =1$ or $\lvert 1+2x1+x2 \rvert=1$. The solution will be in the vertex of the feasible region, unless you choose a vector $c$ perpendicular to one of the constraints. Even in this case due to the way that most solvers are implemented, the solution is mostly likely to be in one of the vertex of the polyhedron.

Comment: Additional question, do you always have the number of variables equal to the number of equations?

Comment: good question and the answer is no. we have more equations than variables. so my example would have been more clear if i had introduced another equation: let's say $|1-x_2-x_2|$ for the third one. And I'm only interested in finding all vertices of the white region.